# WinForms приложение и загрузка файлов через WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, асинхронность

У меня есть отдельный контракт для загрузки файлов.

Клиент я создаю, когда пользователь заходит на отдельную форму и нажимает кнопку загрузить.

На главной форме нажимается кнопка->открывается форма загрузки->нажимается кнопка загрузки и в этой кнопке код такого вида:

```
 using (var client = new FileUploadClient())
    {
        Stream file = new FileStream(filePathBox.Text, FileMode.Open);
        client.Upload(dictInfo, file);
    }
```

Когда это происходит, то разумеется форма подвисает.

Как можно исправить это? Если я прикручу асинхронность, то это поможет мне закрыть форму и продолжить передавать файл в фоне?

Хотелось так же, как-нибудь уведомлять главную форму о процессе загрузки.

Comment: *"закрыть форму"* -- а если при загрузке произойдет ошибка, как пользователь об этом узнает?

Comment: Я ,немного, подправил вопрос.

Comment: В таком случае почему бы вам не запускать код загрузки в главной форме? А дочерняя форма просто будет при закрытии возвращать значение `filePathBox.Text`.

Comment: А это идея. Было бы совсем неплохо, если бы вы дали пример с async и await.

Comment: Добавил ответ, посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Честный `async/await` получится только если сам сервис (и вслед за ним `FileUploadClient`) будет предоставлять асинхронный метод `UploadAsync`. В отсутствии его можно воспользоваться `Task.Run()`. Код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
private async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    try
    {
        using (var form = new UploadForm())
        {
            if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // предполагается, что у формы UploadForm есть свойство FilePath,
                // которое возвращает путь
                var filePath = form.FilePath;
                using (var client = new FileUploadClient())
                {
                    Stream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    await client.UploadAsync(dictInfo, file);
                    // если асинхронного метода у сервиса нет, то можно так:
                    // await Task.Run(() => client.UploadAsync(dictInfo, file))
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка загрузки файла: " + e.Message);
        // или любым другим способом сообщаем об ошибке
    }
    finally
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```